# How to solve LWE/RLWE under partial information about $s$

Tags: lattice-crypto, attack, lwe, ring-lwe

For LWE/RLWE, it's difficult to find $s$ from $\left(A, b = As + e\right)$. But if the partial information of $s$ is leakaged, such as partial $s$ or parity of $s$, how easy would it become to solve LWE?

I don't know much about the algorithm for attacking LWE/RLWE, if there is some relevant literature recommended that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you know is the parity of $s$ then you can rule out half of possible solutions, so no real improvement will happen.

If there is more substantial information, there can be improvements but the situation gets quite technical. There is a 2020 talk entitled *LWE with side information: attacks and concrete security estimation*

[Leo Ducas, CWI, talk at the Simons Institute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRMtKtbx1Yo)

that may be a good point for you to start. There may be other relevant talks during that workshop called Lattices:From Theory to Practice, in April 2020.